# WPF Does rectangle stroke thickness affect location?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need a quick advice on drawing rectangles for printing. If I define

```
new drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown), 
                                 new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 3), 
                                 new Rect(new Point (1, 1), new Size(Width, Height)))
```

lies the left upper outermost corner of the rectangle on (1, 1) or is there an offset because of the stroke thickness?

I already tried some variations to figure it out, but always get different results and can not find a pattern there.

Edit:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Point start = new Point(1.5, 1.5);
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown), new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 3), new Rect(start, new Size(Width-2.5, Height-2.5)));

        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
```

I tried that, assuming the reference point of the rectangle is located in the middle of the stroke with 3 thickness. That seems to be right, at least at left and upper side of the rectangle. I also do have a margin defined, with Thickness 1.

Width and Height correspond to printableWidth and printableHeight. Therefore I go from (1.5, 1.5) to (Width-2.5, Height-2.5). 1 for the margin and 1.5 to be in the middle of the stroke. But looking at the print, the rectangle does not fit at right and bottom sides.

Comment: Could you show the tests you did and the inconsistencies you found?

Comment: I believe that lines have zero width and the strokes are applied on top of these lines but that should be easy to test by doing some simple drawings and looking at an enlarged screenshot. Note that your drawing may be starting at a subpixel offset because of the surroundings and you need to avoid that when testing.

Comment: @Martin, does that mean for a stroke of 4px width, 2px of the rendered line would be left of the zero width line, and 2 to the right for a vertical line?  So for the left vertical of the rectangle here, the line would extend from -1 to 3 in terms of its x coordinate?

Comment: Anti-aliasing can easily throw you off track :) also the use of SnapsToDevicePixels could help/interfere. Also, if the containing canvas(?) is scaled, that could easily mess things up.

Comment: As far as I know it is actually recommended to use the SnapsToDevicePixels in most cases.  I usually set that on the root window for it to trickle down to the controls.

Comment: @MikeW: Yes, that is what I **believe** but I have not verified it. It makes sense though that the geometry does not get modified by the stroke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test this yourself, draw two rectangles at the same position, with different coloured borders.

```
new drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown), 
                             new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 6),
                             new Rect(new Point (1, 1), new Size(Width, Height)));
// Note: second rectangle should have a *smaller* stroke thickness
new drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown), 
                             new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 3), 
                             new Rect(new Point (1, 1), new Size(Width, Height)));
```

If the brush width affects the position of the rectangle, you'll see the red border around the edge of the second rectangle. No border, no effect.

Answer (score 1):

It would be pretty easy to simply test your hypothesis... perhaps even quicker than asking a question here:

```
<Grid Height="230">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Black" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Width="1" Height="230" Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Width="200" Height="50" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" Width="200" Height="50" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="10" Width="200" Height="50" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="15" Width="200" Height="50" />
    <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Black" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Width="1" Height="230" Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Here, you can see that the different `StrokeThickness` values make absolutely no difference to the size or positions of the `Rectangle`s.

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/OIUzdkY.png)
Both rectangles have same size and starting point, but the red one has stroke thickness 30 and the black one has 20. So it seems, it is exactly the opposite.

Comment: I just added the description. Someone just talked to me, therefore it took a litte longer. Sorry for that.

Comment: Interesting... perhaps you should use XAML then instead, which *doesn't* suffer from that problem?

Comment: XAML would be an option, yes. Infact I wanted to avoid it, because I have more experience creating the page layout programmatically. But since here is this issue already, and I am afraid there will be a few more, I will give XAML a try. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using XAML and [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) is definitely preferred over using procedural code in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the total space occupied by a control is bound by its hosting UIElement and cannot logically extend beyond these boundaries unless you specifically set it up to do so.  The ClipToBounds setting will visually truncate anything extending beyond these bounds.

Or you are working with Adorners.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answers here, don't confuse `StrokeThickness` with `BorderThickness`. The `FrameworkElement` inheritance hierarchy has different branches

- `Shape` which includes the UI-ready `Rectangle` class discussed here versus...
- `Decorator` framing elements with a `Child` property where the frames have thickness, e.g. `Border` ...
- `Control`, usually with some concept of `Content`, and some of which may also mimic or expose their own `BorderThickness`/`BorderBrush` properties from `Decorator`

For the purposes of the current question, modifying the `StrokeThickness` or `BorderThickness` on any `FrameworkElement` can only influence its location if:

1. The ***element itself*** first decides that the change affects its own overall size. If the change doesn't affect its own actual size, then there's no way its location can move. But if the element's `DesiredSize` property does indeed change, then this change will be noticed by the element's layout parent, giving the second condition...
2. ***...and also***, if as a result of a `DesiredSize` change, the ***layout parent decides to move the element***.

So the correct answer to the question as posed is "possibly," because it depends on both the particular element in question (`Rectangle` in the OP's case) **as well as** the layout parent to which it is attached.

For the OP's particular example, explicitly setting the `Width` and `Height` properties on `Rectangle` is interpreted as requesting the final overall size, which will include the full outer extent of its Stroke. This mode has the effect of always reducing the inner area, because the Stroke will always be taken from, or "forced into" the **inside** of the overall dimensions, because it's more important for the final `DesiredSize` to agree with `Width/Height`.

Furthermore, I believe `Rectangle` will never "grow" its size for the purpose of satisfying an overly-fat `StrokeThickness` that fills beyond the entire interior of the shape. So, since condition (1.) can never be satisfied for `Rectangle`, the other condition is moot, and it is therefore the case that ***changing the `StrokeThickness` on a `Rectangle` can never cause it to move***.

I modified the code @Sheridan provided to compare the use of the `Shape`-derived element `Rectangle`--which doesn't contain any layout children **(left column)**--with `Decorator`-derived element `Border`, containing a `TextBlock` as a child element that reports the interior available size **(right column)**. You can see that as the `StrokeThickness` changes, the `ActualWidth/ActualHeight` of the `Rectangle` itself do not change, but that's not the case for the `TextBlock` **contained inside** the `Border` element.

[image]

Here's the experimentation code, in case anyone wants to play with it further:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Insert Grid.Resources (shown separately below) here -->

    <Rectangle x:Name="r1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" StrokeThickness="1" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Target="{x:Reference r1}" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="r2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" StrokeThickness="5" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Target="{x:Reference r2}" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="r3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" StrokeThickness="10" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Target="{x:Reference r3}" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="r4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" StrokeThickness="15" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Target="{x:Reference r4}" />

    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1" Child="{StaticResource dt}" />
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="5" Child="{StaticResource dt}" />
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="10" Child="{StaticResource dt}" />
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="15" Child="{StaticResource dt}" />

</Grid>
```

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock x:Key="dt"
               x:Shared="False" 
               Foreground="White" 
               DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.ActualWidth,StringFormat='ActualWidth: {0}',Mode=OneWay}" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.ActualHeight,StringFormat='ActualHeight: {0}',Mode=OneWay}" />
    </TextBlock>

    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White"
                            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Width="{Binding Path=Target.ActualWidth}"
                            Height="{Binding Path=Target.ActualHeight}">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Target.ActualWidth,StringFormat='ActualWidth: {0}',Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <LineBreak />
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Target.ActualHeight,StringFormat='ActualHeight: {0}',Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="common_style" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource common_style}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Navy" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource common_style}">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Navy" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```